# What is the meaning of || after test condition in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

New to Bash scripting. I came across this line in the script file which I find difficult to understand

```
[ "$variable" ] || echo 'variable is unset or empty!' >&2
```

What is `||` used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the logical OR operator. echo is executed if, and only if, test condition returns a non-zero exit status.

See here for more details:
http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Logical_OR

Answer (score 3):

Roughly translated to English, it means "If it failed, do this instead."

Answer (score 3):

Basically, If the first command succeeds the second will never be executed.

```
1 == 1 || echo 'math is broke'
```

Answer (score 2):

The form of the expression `something || something else` or `something && something else` is called a **compound command**. There can be 2 **or more** commands and you can use `{ ...; ...; }` to collect multiple commands together after each `||` or `&&`. For example, to check that the user provides 2 valid filenames on the command line for a script:

```
[ -f "$1" ] && [ -f "$2" ] || {
    printf "error: invalid input. Usage: %s <file1> <file2>\n" "${0//\//}"
    exit 1
}
```

Which simply requires that the test of the first argument `[ -f "$1" ]` (`&&` and) the test of the second argument `[ -f "$2" ]` are both files making each test evaluate to `true`.  Otherwise (`||` or) print the error message and exit.